# Problem with logging in via identity server on MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, .net-5

**Hello**

I am new to ASP .NET identity & identity server.
I have created a MVC application and I would like to connect it through identityserver4 that through identityserver4 you can thus log in to my MVC application....

Now I almost got it working, only when I login via identityserver & I am sent back to my MVC application I get the following error: "Error loading external login information." (See picture of error below)

I don't know directly how to solve this or where to look for it. I've already did a big search online but haven't found any good results...

[image: error]

**MVC startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddDbContext<ComputerAppDbContext>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository, ComputerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IManager, Manager>();
            
            /*services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));*/
            
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
                
                
                
            });
            
           JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

           services.AddAuthentication(options =>
               {
                   options.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
               })
               .AddCookie(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme)
               .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "IdentityServer", options =>
               {
                
                   options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                   options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
                   options.SaveTokens = true;
                   
                   options.Authority = "https://localhost:5002";

                   options.ClientId = "mvc";
                   options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                   options.ResponseType = "code";
                   
                   options.SaveTokens = true;
                   
               });

        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Computer}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

**IdentityServer4 startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                    // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
                    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
               // .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
            
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

           
        }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); });
        }
```

**IdentityServer config.cs**

```
public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new ApiScope[]
            {
                new ApiScope("openid"),
                new ApiScope("profile"),
            };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[]
            {
               
                new Client
                {

                    ClientId = "mvc",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                    RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc"},
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:5001/signout-oidc",
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://localhost:5001/signout-callback-oidc"},
                    
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    }
                },
            };
    }
```

Comment: `identityServerOptions.AddProfileService<>()` ([See also](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/SSO/blob/master/Central/Sso.Central.Data/Extensions/SsoCentralExtensions.cs#L127))

Comment: I still have the same issue... I added what you said to services.AddIdentityServer into my identity server startup.cs  `.AddProfileService<Services.ProfileService>();`

and used your ProfileService from the URL you shared:
[My ProfileService.cs](https://imgur.com/a/MDBTFCd) &
[My startup.cs](https://imgur.com/oUwTHbJ)

Comment: `options.ResponseType = "code id_token";` or smth like that is missing too

Comment: Doesn't help me any further, unfortunately.
**I added these to my mvc client startup.cs: **
`options.ResponseType = "code";
options.UsePkce = true`

**and have this in my config.cs of identityserver:**
`AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
Enabled = true,
RequireClientSecret = false,
RequirePkce = true`

Comment: And can you check the Visual Studio Output window? Do you see any ERRORs in the Output Window. Usually when there are errors, they appear clearly in the Output window.

Comment: `options.ResponseType = "code id_token";` You absolutely need the `id_token` here

Comment: If I modify it to: `options.ResponseType = "code id_token";`
and the AllowedGrantTypes type to: `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid` & set RequirePkce or false.

Then in my JetBrains Raider console from Identity server I only see this:
`[16:39:18 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService
In addition to an id_token, an access_token was requested. No claims other than sub are included in the id_token. To obtain more user claims, either use the user info endpoint or set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken on the client
 configuration.
`
see more in next comment...

Comment: [Full console output](https://imgur.com/fFbFSJN)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme` instate of `IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme`